# Minimax in Java not working

Tags: java, algorithm, minimax

I'm trying to make my minimax algorithm work for a 8x8 Gomoku board where I have to match 5 in a row/col/diagonal to win! My algorithm doesn't seem to be working properly and I can't pinpoint where it is going wrong!

My generateMoves() method works correctly, it generates all legal moves so I know it's not that. The minimax returns -1,-1 as the best move but then that of course throws an illegalMove error because you can't have -1,-1 on a board from 0,0 to 7,7.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
 private int[] minimax(int depth, Color [][] board) {
          List<int[]> nextMoves = generateMoves(board);

          int bestScore = (me == Color.WHITE) ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
          int currentScore;
          int bestRow = -1;
          int bestCol = -1;

          if (nextMoves.isEmpty() || depth == 0) {
             bestScore = evaluateBoard(board);
          } else {
             for (int[] move : nextMoves) {
                 System.out.println(move[0]+","+move[1]+" THIS WAS ATTEMPTED");
                 board[move[0]][move[1]] = Color.WHITE;
                if (me == Color.BLACK) {  
                   currentScore = minimax(depth - 1, board)[0];
                   if (currentScore > bestScore) {
                      bestScore = currentScore;
                      bestRow = move[0];
                      bestCol = move[1];
                   }
                } else {  // oppSeed is minimizing player
                   currentScore = minimax(depth - 1, board)[0];
                   if (currentScore < bestScore) {
                      bestScore = currentScore;
                      bestRow = move[0];
                      bestCol = move[1];
                   }
                }
                board[move[0]][move[1]] = null;
             }
          }
          return new int[] {bestRow, bestCol};
       }

public int evaluateBoard(Color[][] board) {
    int score = 0;
    // Check all the rows
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int blank = 0;
        int black = 0;
        int white = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8 - 5; ++j) {
            if (board[i][j] == Color.black) {
                black++;
                if (board[i][j + 1] == Color.BLACK) {
                    black++;
                    if (board[i][j + 2] == Color.BLACK) {
                        if (board[i][j + 3] == Color.BLACK) {
                            black++;
                            if (board[i][j + 4] == Color.BLACK) {
                                black++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (board[i][j] == Color.WHITE) {
                white++;
                if (board[i][j + 1] == Color.WHITE) {
                    white++;
                    if (board[i][j + 2] == Color.WHITE) {
                        white++;
                        if (board[i][j + 3] == Color.WHITE) {
                            white++;
                            if (board[i][j + 4] == Color.WHITE) {
                                white++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(black);
        score += scoreChange(black, white);
    }

    // Check all the columns
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
        int blank = 0;
        int black = 0;
        int white = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8 - 5; ++i) {
            if (board[i][j] == Color.black) {
                black++;
                if (board[i + 1][j] == Color.BLACK) {
                    black++;
                    if (board[i + 2][j] == Color.BLACK) {
                        black++;
                        if (board[i + 3][j] == Color.BLACK) {
                            black++;
                            if (board[i + 4][j] == Color.BLACK) {
                                black++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (board[i][j] == Color.WHITE) {
                white++;
                if (board[i + 1][j] == Color.WHITE) {
                    white++;
                    if (board[i + 2][j] == Color.WHITE) {
                        white++;
                        if (board[i + 3][j] == Color.WHITE) {
                            white++;
                            if (board[i + 4][j] == Color.WHITE) {
                                white++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        score += scoreChange(black, white);
    }

    int black = 0;
    int white = 0;
    // Check diagonal (Second)
    for (int i = 7, j = 0; i > 3; --i, ++j) {
        if (board[i][j] == Color.black) {
            black++;
            if (board[i - 1][j + 1] == Color.black) {
                black++;
                if (board[i - 2][j + 2] == Color.black) {
                    black++;
                    if (board[i - 3][j + 3] == Color.black) {
                        black++;
                        if (board[i - 4][j + 4] == Color.black) {
                            black++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (board[i][j] == Color.white) {
            white++;
            if (board[i - 1][j + 1] == Color.white) {
                white++;
                if (board[i - 2][j + 2] == Color.white) {
                    white++;
                    if (board[i - 3][j + 3] == Color.white) {
                        white++;
                        if (board[i - 4][j + 4] == Color.white) {
                            white++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    score += scoreChange(black, white);

    black = 0;
    white = 0;
    // Check Diagonal (First)
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 4; ++i, ++j) {
        if (board[i][j] == Color.black) {
            black++;
            if (board[i + 1][j + 1] == Color.black) {
                black++;
                if (board[i + 2][j + 2] == Color.black) {
                    black++;
                    if (board[i + 3][j + 3] == Color.black) {
                        black++;
                        if (board[i + 4][j + 4] == Color.black) {
                            black++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (board[i][j] == Color.white) {
            white++;
            if (board[i + 1][j + 1] == Color.white) {
                white++;
                if (board[i + 2][j + 2] == Color.white) {
                    white++;
                    if (board[i + 3][j + 3] == Color.white) {
                        white++;
                        if (board[i + 4][j + 4] == Color.white) {
                            white++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    score += scoreChange(black, white);
    return score;
}

private int scoreChange(int black, int white) {
    int change;

    if (black == 5) {
        change = -10000;
    } else if (black == 4 && white == 0) {
        change = -1000;
    } else if (black == 3 && white == 0) {
        change = -100;
    } else if (black == 2 && white == 0) {
        change = -10;
    } else if (black == 1 && white == 0) {
        change = -1;
    } else if (white == 5) {
        change = 10000;
    } else if (white == 4 && black == 0) {
        change = 1000;
    } else if (white == 3 && black == 0) {
        change = 100;
    } else if (white == 2 && black == 0) {
        change = 10;
    } else if (white == 1 && black == 0) {
        change = 1;
    } else {
        change = 0;
    }
    return change;
}
```

Comment: you got your < and > wrong...

Answer (score 0):

If the player is Black, the best score is Integer.Max. Current score is never larger than that, so the best move is never set. For White, the problem is congruent: the best score is Integer.Min, the current score is never smaller.

It's much easier to find bugs like this one with a debugger. Set a breakpoint where you set the moves to -1, then step forward. When you get to those if statements you'll be surprised when your code doesn't step in. You'll take a closer look at the values being compared and then realize your mistake.

Comment: So I basically set the currentScore < > the wrong way round, which I've no fixed but it doesn't seem to be defending nor thinking smarter still

Comment: I don't play the game, and I don't have all your code, so I can't evaluate why your code is not working. (Nor should I.)But I suspect that what you want bestScore to represent is not "the best possible score", but rather "best score I've found up till now." Changing the direction of your comparison just accepts *every* move. Which you would also be able to work out with a debugger.